# Image doesn't show in picturebox c#

Tags: c#, picturebox

I want copy image from one picturebox to another. The code below:

```
PictureBox pictureBoxRain1 = new PictureBox();
pictureBoxRain1.Size = size;
//pictureBoxRain1.Image = (Image)Properties.Resources.kaplja;
pictureBoxRain1.Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\images\kaplja.png");
//pictureBoxRain1.ImageLocation = pictureBoxRain.I;
//pictureBoxRain1.Image = Graphics.FromImage();
//pictureBoxRain1.InitialImage = Properties.Resources.kaplja;
//pictureBoxRain1.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.kaplja;
pictureBoxRain1.Location = new Point(pictureBoxRain.Location.X + pictureBoxGrass.Size.Width + 10, pictureBoxRain.Location.Y);
Controls.Add(pictureBoxRain1);
```

All anothers properties copy perfectly to `pictureBoxRain1` from `pictureBoxRain`, but image doesn't want show. Where is problem? I checked many variants such as copy image from `Properties.Resources`, and reading direct from file and some others(look comments in code above), but nothing works.

Comment: Just found strange effect: when image in png - nothing shows, but when it in jpg or in bmp - white picture box will be seen.

Comment: Just an idea: try adding `pictureBoxRain1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;` to see if perhpas it _is_ showing, but only a small part of it.

Comment: Yes, yes, it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT

Check the `pictureBoxRain1.SizeMode`.

Comment: No, I meant pictureBoxGrass exactly

Comment: @pragmus Just verifying: you meant the location of one picturebox and the width of a different one? (Usually when positioning, the width is added to the location to get the right side of the Control).

Comment: Yes, I take location with the location of one picturebox and add width of the different element

Comment: OK. Updated with what seemed to work according to your comment above.